# Packing data in Python

Tags: python, struct, binary, endianness

I'm trying to use `Struct` in python to pack some data, but experiencing some weird behavior:

My format is:

```
struct.Struct('B B I 15s I')
```

The output is (Pipes added for clarity):

```
ff|01|000022000000|4650766e65564369797a4531416f41|0001000000
```

The first two entries are perfect, and so is the string in the middle. But the integer values I am passing are 34 and 1, respectively, and would expect 00000022, 00000001 instead of the weird 6 byte data that I am getting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at play: endianness and padding. For example, the `00002200000000` is two bytes of zero-padding followed by `0x22` in little-endian encoding:

```
00 00 22 00 00 00
^^^^^             padding
      ^^^^^^^^^^^ 0x22
```

To fix both, specify the desired endianness explicitly:

```
struct.Struct('> B B I 15s I')
```

(The reason this gets rid of the padding is that `struct` only pads structures when you use the default native encoding.)